# parameter to get GA Devices Resolution data from GA Account to Web site

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

I have problem to get GA Devices Resolution data from GA Account to Web site. I had already set-up GA account with web site and that's working fine. I'm facing problem to fetch Device Resolution data : following is the screenshot of data on GA account which I wish to grab from Ga and showed into my website:

[image]

> Please let me know what data dimensions and metrics I need to setup in
>   my PHP CODE:

Please help!!!! Thanks in advanced

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and any errors you are having with that code?

Comment: Hi There, actually there is no error while fetching record but I want to get data belongs to screen resolution. I have done lots of googling but could not get meaningful information...

Comment: There is a handy metrics and dimensions reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=system&jump=ga_screenresolution. Screen resolution is a dimension, so you need to add at least one metric to your query (you cannot have queries without metrics, although queries without a dimension work fine). For everything else, show what you tried and we're ready to help :-)

Comment: This is more of a story, what is your question? Be specific!

Comment: dear experts... what you required more

Comment: Since you say you are using the API we expect some code you are trying to use; as an alternative you could try a query in the Google Analytics Query Explorer. If all you are looking for is the fieldname for the screen resolution data then look at my comment.